# Validation and Callbacks in redis data

Tags: redis

i am using rails. i stored some part of data in mysql database and some in redis. My question is : can we apply callbacks and validation on redis data like in rails?

Answer (score 0):

No - the best you can do is encaspulate your write operations in Lua server-side scripts, which can do the validation work (and trigger Lua callbacks). It is a complete do-it-yourself approach.